# javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: java.io.IOException at time of calling web service

Tags: java, linux, web-services, ubuntu, java-me

Hello
i have Login web service in .Net and calling it from my
J2ME web service client.

it was working perfect and code was working
but as today i started my project and calling same

it is giving me error like

```
javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: java.io.IOException: Error initializing HTTP tunnel connection: 
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Content-type: text/html
Server: Muffin/0.9.3a

        at com.sun.j2mews.xml.rpc.OperationImpl.invoke(OperationImpl.java:283)
        at com.aa.stubs.aa_Stub.complaintList(aa_Stub.java:199)
        at com.aa.gui.form.LoginForm$LoginFormListener.getComplainList(LoginForm.java:128)
        at com.aa.gui.form.LoginForm$LoginFormListener$1.run(LoginForm.java:102)
```

same code is working on different pc

i had test other web service available on web they are even giving same error.

i am using ubantu 9.04 
i had test it on win xp as well as on fedora where it is working

what could be problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution.

my net beans was set to system proxy and i check my company's server setting
where on proxy networking was not allowed.

i just set my net beans with no proxy and problem is solved.